# Getting the error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition, MS Excel 2016 (64 Bit)

I am gettin this error while I'm trying to read the data from Excel into a dataset. I checked the solution and I installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2012 Redistribute from the link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255.

And even after installing I'm still getting the same error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

I'm working on a web application along with my team and for all my colleagues it's working. For me it's not working

Comment: Did you reboot after installing the pre-requisite application? Does the driver show when you run `odbcad32`?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the application and also restarted the system also. How can i run `odbcad32`?

Comment: Start > Run (or Win+R) > `odbcad32` > Press enter or click OK.

Comment: Ok. i will check and let you know. Thank you for quick reply

Comment: Oh, also; your link is for the Office 2010 version of the redist, but you say you're using Excel 2016. You might want to try a newer redist https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all

Comment: Since you have a 64-bit version of Excel installed you must then also installed a 64-bit version of the ACE OLEDB Provider.  **You should ask your IT Administrator to properly configure your system with the appropriate software.**

Comment: ok sure. I will try this one also and let you know @spikey_richie

Comment: The link you provided is to the incorrect version of the Access Database Engine (ADE) you need.  You must be sure you are installing the 64-bit version otherwise it will not work.  What is the full error message.  *You have only provided the first setence of the error message.*  Since you are running Office 2016 you must installed [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all)

Comment: I have installed the 64 bit version only. IT administrator only installed it. But still I'm getting the same error. As of now I'm off work. Tomorrow i will check and let you know @Ramhound

Comment: @AjayGanti - Are you 100% positive you are running the 64-bit verison of Excel in that case?

Comment: Yeah I'm 100% sure that I'm using 64 bit version of Excel. I think I might have installed Office 2010 version of ADE. I will try with 2016 version of ADE as the MS office is 2016 version. @Ramhound

Comment: I got it resolved by checking the Use 64 bit version of IIS Express options of Visual Studio. Then it started reading the data properly from the web application. I apologize for late reply

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by checking the "Use 64 bit version of IIS Express" option of Visual Studio. Then it started reading the data properly from the web application.